# Customising file formating and coding styles in vim?

Tags: formatting

At the moment I use prettier for formatting with vim (via Coc). The issue I have is that prettier is opinionated and, at the same time, inconsistent.

With javascript, functions look like this:

```javascript
function cheese() {
  // stuff here
}
```

In PHP they look like this:

```php
function cheese() 
{
  // stuff here
}
```

I want to be able to have full control over how conditionals, loops and functions look.

Is there a "vim way" of customising this?

I searched online but most solutions mention prettier!

Comment: Read the docs `:h =`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no builtin way to format code with Vim.

However Vim has two formatting commands:

1. `=`
2. `gq`

The first re-indent the content based on the file type.

The second reformat the content using either a VimScript or an external command.

How to associate an external command to a filetype is explained in the following answer: [How to format code in vim using external commands](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/37721/23502)

Comment: See in particular how you can customise Vim's internal `'cindent'` indenting at [`:help cinoptions-values`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#cinoptions-values) and the details of Vim's default PHP indenting at [`:help php-indent`](https://vimhelp.org/indent.txt.html#php-indent)

Comment: Also `gw`, and (as Rich points out) a massive number of options to control formatting and indenting behavior.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, use filters in your own command to call external tools. For example, for C and C++ you can run something like this:

```
" .vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim
command! -buffer Fmt let winsaved = winsaveview() | execute '%! clang-format --style WebKit' | if v:shell_error > 0 | silent undo | endif | call winrestview(winsaved)
```

The same idea is useful for pretty much any other language:

latex: `%! latexindent`

python: `%! black - -q`

go: `%! gofmt`

Comment: This is very similar to `:setlocal formatprg=clang-format` (`latexindent`/etc.), although you could reasonably choose `indentprg`, too.

Comment: I don't think it is so reasonable to use `indentprg` for things that require more than indenting. You could use `formatprg`, but it becomes a big mess with complex logic and not so flexible as it cannot be used in autocommands, which is a common request for this sort of feature.

Comment: I don't follow "complex logic" or "cannot be used in autocommands," since `formatprg` only affects how the builtin `gq` works, which can be incorporated anywhere with `:normal!`…

Comment: Notice the additional commands to restore the view when malformed code triggers an error. For the record, I also use `formatprg` as you described for formatting visual selections.